How to build required files for PDFTEX?
Hello English ins't my first language so forgive me please.  I have been spending a good amount of time and my efforts feel like a hack.
I am following instructions from their site
Tug Site
cd Work        # top build directory
../configure --without-x --disable-shared --disable-all-pkgs \
             --enable-tex --disable-synctex --disable-xetex \
             --enable-missing -C CFLAGS=-g CXXFLAGS=-g
make
cd texk/web2c  # cd engine build directory
make pdftex    #<------ this is my target 

Pdftex compiles , but when I run this ,
./pdflatex caffiene.txt

I receive multiple errors in searching for configuration files and some pdftex.fmt.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2025/dev) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdftex.fmt
Can't exec "kpsewhich": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/mktexfmt line 17.
/usr/bin/mktexfmt: kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT failed, aborting early.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/mktexfmt line 25.
I can't find the format file `pdftex.fmt'!

I managed to add these files from some Perl builder and that seems to be incorrect way to go. I received some error that pdftex.fmt is incorrect.
/home/luser/texlive/2024/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdftex.fmt made by different executable version, strings are different
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)

caffeine.txt
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\section{I need caffeine.}
\chemfig{*6((=O)-N(-H)-(*5(-N=-N(-H)-))=-(=O)-N(-H)-)}
\end{document}

How am I supposed to build this correctly? I am wanting to ultimately retarget this later, but I want to have a concise instruction first. I am not seeing much helpful in the documentation.

as you found, if you just build one component then many scripts will fail as they expect the whole suite. It is much easier to initially build everythng by running the Build script from say a clone of https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source  then later you can build specific component such as pdftex by running make in its directory if you have changed anything.  But are you sure you need to build this at all?

I am guessing yes. I am needing a sort of one stop to make tex into a PDF (image would suffice too).  I plan to make this into a WASM module in the end. So less binary steps, the better. If you have a better idea, let me know please.

have you seen https://manuels.github.io/texlive.js/  ? most online tex systems use a real tex on a server as pdftex typically needs thousands of font files and packages and other stuff so it's quite hostile to being packaged as a module to run on the client (texlivejs does show it's possible though)

This is interesting and seems similar to what I need. I will check it out. -- Thank you.
